# filter items using linq

Tags: linq-to-objects

HI

I have 2 lists, list 1 contains objects and list 2 contains strings, i am trying to filter objects whose name are in the list 2 using following ling query but it doesn't work. Object has a Name property.

`var query =
   from item1 in List1
   let current = item1.Name

   let exclude = from item2 in exceptionList select item2 
   where current != exclude.ToString() 
   select item1;`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you just do...

```
from item1 in List1
where List2.Contains(item1.Name)
select item1
```

Comment: i tried it before using let but it didn't work, it works this time. clearly there was something wrong with what i tried. Thanks.